# Measuring cross-section area of a flexible tube (5mm dia approx)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, volume

I want to measure the avg. inner cross-section area of a flexible tube of outer diameter 5mm. Since the cross-section isn't a circle exactly, use of vernier caliper to measure inner diameter fails. The idea that I wish to try is, to take a tube of known length, fill it with water, then pour the water on to something like a volume flask and from the volume obtained compute the cross-section area.

My questions are, 
1 - how valid does this method sound?
2 - Is there a better way to do this?
3 - How much error would the water stuck in the tube due to surface tension introduce?

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Probably offtopic. Can't you measure the thickness of the tube, though? Keep in mind you have to measure it in a curved state.

Comment: I can measure the thickness, but a 5mm flexible tube isn't exactly 5mm in diameter always, parameters like temperature, liquid pressure comes it. Doing that wont be accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems fine to me. Essentially you're measuring volume by filling it with a fluid, and this is a method commonly used for determining the densities of powders or other materials where it's hard to measure the volume. The method is known as [pycnometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_density#Pycnometer) if you feel the urge to Google it.

To improve the accuracy I would:

1. weigh the tube
2. fill it with water and block the ends
3. weigh it again

That avoids errors introduced by trying to decant the water from the tube into a weighed container.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks a lot - let me test it out and let you know.